# How do I forward SIP calls

Tags: server, software-recommendation, voip

I need to set up a SIP client that forwards calls to Google Voice(via POTS call or alternate)
Could I use asterisk for this?
I have an always-on Ubuntu VPS which could be used for this.

Comment: Yes, you could use asterisk for this.  Last time I checked, installing asterisk was not at all straight-forward though.  For such a limited application, it would probably be much easier to use the Asterisk@Home or AsteriskNOW iso as base media.

Comment: @hbdgaf do you know whether Google voice supports sip?

Comment: Here's how some guy was doing it at one point https://hobbiesbytwinclouds.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/how-to-make-and-receive-call-using-google-voice-without-xmpp/

Comment: @hbdgaf looks quite promising, will try it later today. I'd mark it as correct if you submit as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) has a functionality called [Call Transfer](https://jitsi.org/index.php/Development/CallTransfer) that should produce the result you seek:

> One useful feature of IP telephony is the fact that users can easily transfer their calls to someone else.
>
> Imagine for example that you are talking to a friend who’s asking you about your notes of a particular class or lecture. You don’t have them but you know that another friend of yours does. It would be nice if you could simply forward the call to that new person so that your two friends could arrange the transfer by themselves.

An alternative would be [Twinkle](http://www.twinklephone.com/); from the [manual](http://www.twinklephone.com/manual.html):

> When you want to transfer a standing call to another party you press the Xfer button. This will popup a dialog box from which you can choose what kind of call transfer you want.
>
> - Blind call transfer
> - Transfer with consultation
> - Transfer to other line
>
> Call transfer will only work if your SIP provider and/or the remote party supports the proper SIP extensions.

Comment: So would this forward unconditionally?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: so would sip be an alternative to using my Google voice pots number? If so, what would it be?